# Django and mongodb

Tags: python, django, mongodb

Any good tutorial for python django mongodb?

I have python 3.7.3 installed.
I grabbed django 1.6 from https://github.com/django-nonrel/django (that's really old).
Followed the instruction of https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html

The "python manager.py runserver" show some htmlparser errors.

File "D:\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html.py", line 14, in 
    from .html_parser import HTMLParser, HTMLParseError
  File "D:\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\html_parser.py", line 12, in 
    HTMLParseError = _html_parser.HTMLParseError
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'

Any recommendations to have them work together?

Comment: Why have you installed an old version of django? Why do you think that error has anything to do with Mongodb?

Comment: have you tried https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/get-started/.?

Answer (score 0):

The django-norel was really old and still come out from google radar.

Thanks for the advice.
Now, I can get it work with "djongo".